# Prove that this infinite sum involving metrics is also a metric

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

The following is a question from a previous assignment that I was unable to complete. Any assistance on how to complete this would be appreciated.

Let $\varrho_i: X\times X\to \Bbb R^+$ with $i\in\Bbb N$ be a family of metrics. Show that
$$
\bar\varrho=\sum_{i=0}^\infty\frac{1}{2^i}\frac{\varrho_i}{1+\varrho_i}
$$
is a metric.

Comment: Can you show $\overline \varrho(x,y)\ge 0$ and $\overline \varrho(x,y)=0$ if and only if $x=y$? Can you show the series always converges?

Comment: Does it converge simply because the limit as $i\to\infty$ of $\frac{1}{2^i}$ is 0?

Comment: No, $\frac 1 n \to 0$ as well, but $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac 1 n$ diverges.

Comment: @Zac You're close, though... do you know what a [geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series) is?

Comment: Ok, so $\sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac{1}{2^i}$converges and $\frac{\rho_i}{1+\rho_i}<1$. Therefore $\sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac{1}{2^i}\frac{\rho_i}{1+\rho_i}$ also converges and this satisfies the condition whereby a metric must always be defined? 
I can see that non-negativity, identity of indiscernibles, and symmetry follow from the metrics $\rho_i$. What about the triangle inequality?

Comment: the triangle inequality comes from the fact that for each $i$, $\dfrac{\rho_i}{1+ \rho_i}$ defines a metric